# Can regex be used to compare 2 numbers in a string?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I was wondering if regex can be used to compare 2 numbers in a string. For example, field goals made and attempted, "0-0". I have a regex to match that pattern: `\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}` but I want to take it a step further. I want to make sure that it won't return a match if the number of field goals made is larger than the number of field goals attempted, i.e. going "20-10" which is not possible for obvious reasons.

Comment: No, you can't do that in a regex. Do it in your PHP or JS code instead.

Comment: @revo: That does not ensure that the second number is mathematically larger than the first (or vice versa), which is what the question asks.

Comment: @KenWhite OP never said *doing it in regex* he said whether *regex can be used*.

Comment: @revo: And the answer is *No, a regex cannot be used to ensure one number is mathematically larger than another as this question asks.* Read the question again.

Comment: @wlc I think I stopped reading too quickly. RegEx is not a tool for comparing numbers in mathematical manner, even though you might find a way to do this specific task with it.

Comment: I already have functions in my JS and PHP code that checks if the made vs attempted ratio is valid. I was just wondering if I was missing something in regex that could make that check a little more efficient. Tinkering with conditions, look aheads and look behinds yielded no results. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @KenWhite If you read my first comment you had seen it was doing a simple check of same sequence of digits of either side. So for sure I wasn't supporting math operations.

Comment: @revo: Yes, I know. That's why I pointed out the mistake. :-)

Comment: My question would be why you have a string that combines both of them in the first place. You can format them that way for display, but should keep them separate for all other purposes, which would make the task of validating much easier.

Comment: @KenWhite UI/UX is informing this decision. It's much more convenient to simply type 0-10, 2-12, 10-10, especially if it's accompanied by a mask, than tabbing in one input field, entering a the number of field goals made, then tabbing into another field to enter the number of attempts.

Comment: I have far different input from users about UI/UX. It's extremely irritating to fix typos/mistakes when values are inappropriately combined, and much more complex to validate data entered (and indicate an erroneous value clearly).